# Solution to $y''+k y = 0$ with complex exponentials and sine and cosine

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am a little confused about the solution to $y''+ ky=0$. Obviously, one can write the fundamental system as: $\{\exp(i \sqrt{k} x),\,\exp(-i \sqrt{k} x)\}$, but also as $\{\cos(\sqrt{k} x),\,\sin(\sqrt{k}x)\}$. Now, I cannot see how to make these two solutions correspond. From the first system, the general solution is:

$$A e^{i\sqrt{k}\, x} + B e^{-i\sqrt{k}\, x} = \ldots =(A + B) \cos{(\sqrt{k}\,x)} + (A-B)i\sin{(\sqrt{k}\,x)}$$

From the second, the general solution is:
$$ C \cos{(\sqrt{k}\,x)} + D \sin{(\sqrt{k}\,x)} $$
 leading to the relations $ A+B = C$ and $A-B=i D$. If I want to push this further by assuming $C$ and $D$ are real (because in the end, I want some real solution), then it follows: let $A = a + i\alpha$ and $B = b+i\beta$:

$$ C = A + B = a + b + i(\alpha + \beta)$$ but as $C\in\mathbb{R}$ then $\alpha+\beta=0$.
$$ D = -i(A-B) = -i(a-b) - (\alpha-\beta) $$ but again $D\in\mathbb{R}$ then $a-b=0$ leading to:

$$ a + i\alpha = A\\
a - i\alpha = B$$ and thus $A$ and $B$ are complex conjugates which is strange because on one side I have no relation between $C$ and $D$ and on the other $A$ and $B$ are so tightly bound together.

Comment: Specifying that the solutions are real imposes conditions on the equation, so it should come as no surprise that it imposes conditions on the coefficients of the solutions. You can think of it like this: if we assume complex solutions, the general solution is as you have written with $A,B\in\mathbb C$, which essentially gives us four free real parameters (the real and imaginary parts of $A$ and $B$). If you assume real solutions, we now only have two free real parameters, and $A$ and $B$ now must each depend on these parameters.

Answer (score 2):

$e^{i\sqrt{k}x}$ and $e^{-i\sqrt{k}x}$ are conjugate so it is demanding that 
$$Ae^{i\sqrt{k}x} + Be^{-i\sqrt{k}x}$$ be real that has led to A and B being conjugate.  There is an equally strong restriction on $C$ and $D$: $im(C) = 0$ and $im(D) = 0$.  From a real point of view, both solution spaces have dimension 2; just different bases.